# Devexpress Appointment Scheduler

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

When i try to open an appointment scheduler it is giving the following error :

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm'
>   to type
>   'DevExpress.Web.ASPxScheduler.VerticalAppointmentTemplateContainer'."

but before it was working fine.

pls help...

Answer (score 0):

I've just got the same issue.

If you changed your shcheduler for example view type to timeline with grouped by resource. 
You need to use HorizontalAppointmentTemplateContainer with your custom template control.